# how to hide a button that is bound to a command that cannot execute?

Tags: wpf, binding

Instead of disabling the button which happens automatically, i would like to hide (or rather collapse the visibility of) the button.

Comment: this is not helping... i know how to set a property.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use a Style and Triggers, assuming that the command is in charge of setting the Button enabled/disabled:

```
        <Button x:Name="btnMoveUp"
                Command="{x:Static local:Window1.MoveItemUp}">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Note that you can define this Style at a higher scope and share it - I just put it right with the Button for a more compressed example.

Answer (score 25):

The same behavior without style and trigger, if the Visibility property is not bound yet.

```
Command={Binding MyCommand}
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BTVC}}"
```

Where BTVC is a BooleanToVisibilityConverter (that is a must have).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` and bind to a bool as [described here](http://bembengarifin.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/setting-visibility-of-wpf-control-through-binding/).

Comment: this is a possibility, thanks. can this be done without adding an extra property? trying to reduce the amount of code.